# Selecting a random entry based on conditional

Tags: templating, random

I'm trying to select 1 random entry out of a section based on whether a field has content (`schedulerBio`). I can get all the entries based on the conditional but can't seem to randomize a single selection. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('team').limit(1).find() if entry.schedulerBio|length %}
... stuff
{% endfor }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Think this should work:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('team').limit(1).order('RAND()').schedulerBio(':notempty:') %}
   ...stuff
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! That worked perfectly. I had not tried notempty.